# Typescript: What's the meaning of a '!' at the end of an attribution

Tags: typescript

I was looking through angular2 code and saw a few things such as:

```
this._outlets[name] = undefined !;
```

What is the meaning of that `!` at the end? Couldn't find anything on google about it :(

Comment: Not sure what it means, although it's compiled to just `undefined` by TSC. Check [this sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20test%20%3D%20undefined%20!%3B%20)

Comment: It tells the compiler that undefined is not undefined See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/450611

Comment: Hey, that's cool @weirdan!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: I'm still not sure what's the point in that particular example. Here's the code from [angular](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/5293794316cc1b0f57d5d88b3fefdf6ae29d0d97/packages/router/src/router_outlet_map.ts#L28)

Comment: @LeonardoChaia Agree, makes sense and it's cool when you want to access some property but not yet sure what : `undefined is not undefined` means :)

Comment: The index signature defined for `_outlets` does not accept undefined values, you cannot assign `this._outlets[name] = undefined`. ` undefined !` fools the compiler into believing that `undefined is not undefined`, but at run-time `undefined` will be assigned to `this._outlets[name] `

Answer (score 20, accepted):

After some checking I found out that it is indeed telling the compiler that `undefined is not undefined` :)

In case you run the compiler with `--strictNullChecks` trying to assign undefined to something such as a string for example will yielf in the following error: `Type "undefined" is not assignable to type "string"`. If you use `undefined !` you basically bypass this check and tsc won't give you an error for it.

Answer (score 4):

This post-fix expression operator **!** may be used to assert that its operand cannot be *null* or *undefined* during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Its called **non-null assertion operator**. Its **telling the compiler** that you are sure that the value won't be ***null or undefined.*** It's a way to assert to the TypeScript compiler that you've manually checked that a value isn't null and you're telling it to **proceed without emitting a null check.**