# Typescript exclamation parentheses

Tags: angular, typescript

I've come across this statement on [the angular website](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe):

```js
this.resolve !('hi there!');
```

I have no idea what the `!` might mean in this context.
I've come across the [non-null assertion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci/42274019) but I somehow don't think that's what it is here. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is the [non-null assertion operator.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator) Note that the type for `this.resolve` is `Function|null` so it can possibly be null.

It is added so that the compiler stops complaining about `this.resolve` being possibly null with `strictNullChecks` compiler option turned on.

Comment: Of course if they just dropped the `this.arrived` flag and simply tested `this.resolve` the code would be shorter and wouldn't need the assertion operator.