# What dose it mean using [...parent.path !] . the?

Tags: angular, typescript

I go over the angular form module and I saw a syntax I don't recognize
[...parent.path !, name];

is it typescript syntax?

it can be found at [this link](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts) which is angular github code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Comment: `...`  is the spread operator, and ! indicates to the compiler that the object won't be null

Comment: thanks nice to know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As indicate **[here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator)**.

> A new `!` post-fix expression operator ***may be used to assert that its
>   operand is non-null and non-undefined*** in contexts where the type
>   checker is unable to conclude that fact. Specifically, the operation
>   `x!` produces a value of the type of `x` with `null` and `undefined` excluded.
>   Similar to type assertions of the forms `<T>x` and `x` as `T`, the `!`
>   non-null assertion operator is simply removed in the emitted
>   JavaScript code.

```
// Compiled with --strictNullChecks
function validateEntity(e?: Entity) {
    // Throw exception if e is null or invalid entity
}

function processEntity(e?: Entity) {
    validateEntity(e);
    let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
}
```

It indicates **non-null** value.