# Typescript not detecting null check and complaining about argument not assignable

Tags: typescript, null

So I have a function that requires a certain non nullable type. Before calling the function I check if the input parameter is not null but, apparently, typescript can't understand that and complains saying:

> Argument of type 'HermiteOctreeNode | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HermiteOctreeNode'.
>
> Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'HermiteOctreeNode'.

```
if (node.nodeType !== NODE_TYPE_LEAF && node.nodeType !== NODE_TYPE_PSEUDO) {
for (let i = 0; i < node.children.length; i++) {
  if (node.children[i] != null) {
    rebuildOctreeNode(node, /* node.children[i]  HERE /*, i);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are absolutely certain that the operator is not null, you can use the [non-null assertion operator](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#non-null-assertion-operator) (`!`):

```
if (node.children[i] !== null) {
    rebuildOctreeNode(node, node.children[i]!, i);
}
```

There's more information about this operator on this question: [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Answer (score 3):

As another solution, you can store the array value in a variable and it will resolve your issues:

```
const child = node.children[i];

if (child != null) {
  rebuildOctreeNode(node, child, i);
}
```