# How to fix Typescript string guard not ruling out string enum?

Tags: typescript

Here's a type I'm working with:

```
type EmbeddingsSummary = { [path: string]: Embedding | WontGetEmbeddingReason }
```

`WontGetEmbeddingReason` is a string enum, so I expected that

```
(typeof embeddings[relativePath] === 'string') ? undefined :
    getCosineSimilarity(embeddings[relativePath], searchEmbedding)
```

will work fine (to be clear: `Embedding` is an array). However (with `getCosineSimilarity` expecting `Embedding` as the first argument), TypeScript complains:

> Argument of type 'Embedding | WontGetEmbeddingReason' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Embedding'.

so in fact I'm currently using a mediocre workaround (casting):

```
(typeof embeddings[relativePath] === 'string') ? undefined :
    getCosineSimilarity(embeddings[relativePath] as Embedding, searchEmbedding)
```

Why TS doesn't deduce that if `typeof embeddings[relativePath] === 'string'` then `embeddings[relativePath]` is actually an `Embedding`? How can I fix this check?

Comment: Try storing `embeddings[relativePath]` in a variable, so you aren't accessing it by key twice. TS is not great at narrowing dynamically-accessed properties like this.

Comment: Very similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50035288/12299000) - see the [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50035479/12299000).

Comment: @kaya3 thanks, this resolves the issue indeed. In fact, this may be something reasonable, as far as I remember JS may have custom getters that may have side-effects and hence the value may be different after second reading