# How to disable typechecking when using a logical operator or when the final result is allowed to be undefined

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to use an object as possibly undefined. Although typescript won't let me, because it cannot access the "undefined" property.

So Imagine I have a type called StackOverflowUser and another called UserPreferences

```js
  type UserPreferences = {
    useDarkMode?: string
    showUnicorns?: boolean
  }


  type StackOverflowUser = {
     name: string
     preferences: UserPreferences | undefined
  }
```

Now what I'm trying to do is something like this

```js
 const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (
     user.preferences.useDarkMode || 
     user.preferences.showUnicorns
 )
```

Although, typescript won't let me access the useDarkMode property because is possibly undefined. The thing is, I know that :P

Some of the things I have tried:

```js
const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (
  (user.preferences.useDarkMode as undefined | boolean) || 
  (user.preferences.showUnicorns as undefined | boolean)
) 

const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (
  user.preferences.useDarkMode || 
  user.preferences.showUnicorns
 ) || false

const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (
  (user.preferences.useDarkMode || false) || 
  (user.preferences.showUnicorns || false)
) 

const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (
  (user.(preferences as any).useDarkMode as any) || 
  (user.preferences.showUnicorns || false)
)
```

In the end. The only solution I found is very verbose, And cannot be used in my case (JSX component)

Solution:

```js
  const userIsTryingNewFeatures = (user.preferences) && (
    (user.preferences.useDarkMode &&
      user.preferences.useDarkMode) || 
    (user.preferences.showUnicorns &&
      user.preferences.showUnicorns) || 
  )
```

## TLDR;

Is there a way to suppress accessing `undefined` properties from objects? Or is there a way to disable type checking when using the Logical Operator?

Comment: Have you tried `user.preferences && (user.preferences.useDarkMode || 
     user.preferences.showUnicorns)`?

Comment: Why `preferences: UserPreferences | undefined` instead of `preferences?: UserPreferences`? Either way if `preferences` can be `undefined` you have to make sure it exists before referencing one of the properties. Why would you want to suppress a possible `ReferenceError`? What advantage does it have other than making the code less verbose?

Answer (score 2):

If you're certain that `user.preferences` is non-null, use the [non-null assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci):

```
user.preferences!.useDarkMode
```

That being said, TypeScript is trying to warn you of a runtime `TypeError` so a better approach is to be explicit per Tholle's suggestion:

```
user.preferences && (user.preferences.useDarkMode || user.preferences.showUnicorns)
```

The former approach *will* result in a `TypeError` when `user.preferences` is null. It's primarily useful when you have code earlier that has verified that the non-null assertion is safe but TypeScript isn't smart enough (yet) to figure that out. Even then, you'll often be able to resolve the issue with a [user-defined type guard](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#user-defined-type-guards).

Comment: I've tried the non-null assertion operator, although, those values could be undefined. What I really wanted is some way to tell typescript that there's no problem on being undefined there! What I was looking for is some kind of safe navigation (like the proposed `?` operator) to make the syntax easier to read. 
Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: Ah, yeah! That would be nice but alas it's only a proposal for now: https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining.