# How to avoid 'Object is possibly null' warning on properties that will be populated in the future

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am using Typescript with vue. The problem is that I have declared an instance property named `categoryList` which will be populated when the component renders on the runtime with an array from an api call. So, when I am referencing this property in another method like this:

`this.categoryList.length && this.categoryList[0]` since I know that this will have some value when the method executes

TS gives me a warning.

Since categoryList will be an array of Object, if I access it like this

```
this.categoryList[0].source_id
```

I get the following warning

[image]

Instead, if I access it like this `this.categoryList[0]`

I get the following warning

[image]

But, how can I avoid this kind of warning for such cases where value will be assigned on run time in the future to an instance property being refernced.

```
class Alerts extends Vue {
    private activeView: number = VIEW.NEW; 
    private categoryList: [] = [];

    mounted() {
      this.fetchCategories()
    }

    /*
     * method to fetch from an api call
     */
    fetchCategories() {
      this.$axios.get(CATEGORY_URL).then((res) => {
          categoryList = res.data
      })
    }

    doSomethingWithCategories() {
       // have to use categoryList here
       const use = this.categoryList.length && this.categoryList[0] // This warns me that Object is possibly undefined
       // ...
    }

}
```

As advised by @Mark, I am already using conditionals to ensure value availability but still getting warning.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Post the exact and complete error/warning you get.

Comment: For one thing, you've declared that your `categoryList` as an empty array in `private categoryList: [] = []`. Then `categoryList = res.data` should also give you an error because of invalid assignment (but probably also because it's supposed to be `this.categoryList = res.data`). We would need to see the actual code (or an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)), and as JB said, the actual error.

Comment: I am using axios and res is of type `AxiosResponse<any>` and res.data is of type `any` . So, assigning it to categoryList doesnt popup any warning.

Comment: The compiler doesn't seem to take into account the left part of the boolean operation. It do understand `if` blocks, so I would try to enclose it in a conditional like `if(this.categoryList[0] !== undefined) {...}` or may be even `if(this.categoryList.length > 0) {...}`. Also may work using `this.categoryList.forEach(...)`, just taking the first element and exiting the loop.

Comment: `if(this.categoryList.length > 0) {...}` works same as `if(this.categoryList.length){...}` since 0 is `falsey`. Also, seems like accessing the property by index will popup a warning even in the conditional check.` this.categoryList.forEach(...)` seems a bit hackey but get rids of the warning

Comment: Well, indeed, `forEach` is not a good idea because it can't be stopped. Better this:
`for (const categoryItem of this.categoryList) { ...; break; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your issue:

```js
 private categoryList: [] = [];
```

Should be:

```js
 private categoryList: YourDataType[] = [];
```

When you define an array as type `[]` you are essentially telling Typescript that the value of this variable will only ever be a tuple of size 0, or `[]`.

Comment: indeed, this was the case. Fixed my issue by declaring instance property like this:
`private categoryList: object[] = [];`

Answer (score -1):

An interesting thing to note: If you know for sure that categoryList will have a value when code executes, then you can get away with the warning with following hack. But its not advisable to use it often as we should apply null/undefined checks wherever required.

```
this.categoryList![0].source_id
```

! tells typescript that the object preceding it will always have a value when the code runs.

For more info, please check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci).

Comment: The null coalesce operator shouldn't be abused and I don't think it's a good idea to advise people new to typescript to use it at all.

Comment: @PatrickMichaelsen That's why I had written the disclaimer [But its not advisable to use it often as we should apply null/undefined checks wherever required.] !