# type guard for the value shift from an array

Tags: typescript

```
const arr: number[] = []
const func = (n: number): void => {
    console.log(n)
}
arr.push(222)
if (arr.length > 0) {
    func(arr.shift())
}
```

I want to invoke `func` with a number as argument. However, I got this error message in IDE:

> Argument of type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to parameter
>   of type 'number'.   Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type
>   'number'.ts(2345)

How can I resolve this problem without setting the parameter form `n: number` to `n: number | undefined`?

Comment: Since you already have an undefined check: `func(arr.shift()!)`

Comment: FMI see https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273853

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) (I thought to elaborate an answer, but it's just rehashing this question...)