# What does the ! mean in the angular syntax?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I've been seeing this creep up in a few places now but have not found any answers on it.

I'm curious what the '!' bang does in the angular syntax.

[image]

Comment: see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Comment: closing as duplicate, I thought it was angular specific.

Answer (score 9):

From the [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#the-non-null-assertion-operator---):

> ### The non-null assertion operator ( ! )
>
> As of Typescript 2.0, you can enforce strict null checking with the
> `--strictNullChecks` flag. TypeScript then ensures that no variable is unintentionally `null` or `undefined`.
>
> In this mode, typed variables disallow `null` and `undefined` by default.
> The type checker throws an error if you leave a variable unassigned or
> try to assign `null` or `undefined` to a variable whose type disallows
> `null` and `undefined`.
>
> The type checker also throws an error if it can't determine whether a
> variable will be `null` or `undefined` at runtime. You may know that can't
> happen but the type checker doesn't know. You tell the type checker
> that it can't happen by applying the post-fix [non-null assertion
> operator (!)](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator).
>
> The **Angular non-null assertion operator (!)** serves the same purpose in
> an Angular template.
>
> For example, after you use `*ngIf` to check that `hero` is defined, you
> can assert that `hero` properties are also defined.
>
> ```
> <!-- No hero, no text -->
> <div *ngIf="hero">
>   The hero's name is {{hero!.name}}
> </div>
> ```
>
> When the Angular compiler turns your template into TypeScript code, it
> prevents TypeScript from reporting that `hero.name` might be `null` or
> `undefined`.
>
> Unlike the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#safe-navigation-operator), the non-null assertion operator
> does not guard against `null` or `undefined`. Rather it tells the
> TypeScript type checker to suspend strict null checks for a specific
> property expression.
>
> You'll need this template operator when you turn on strict null
> checks. It's optional otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

Its called the ["**Non-null assertion operator**"](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html) and has nothing todo with Angular perse, it is from typescript.

```
let s = e!.name;  // Assert that e is non-null and access name
```