# Using web component without registering as a custom element?

Tags: javascript, web-component, custom-element

Is it possible to instantiate a web component without registering it to the  `CustomElementRegistry`? consider a simple component:

```
export class MyCustomElm extends HTMLElement {

  constructor() {
    super();

    this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    this.shadowRoot!.innerHTML = `
      <div>Hello world</div>
    `;
  }
}

// Is it really required?
customElements.define('my-custom-elm', MyCustomElm);
```

I am using **storybook** for building a library of web-component. All the examples/demos are web components. The code will always use constructor syntax, i.e. `new MyCustomElm()` to initialize the component. It will never be used via plain HTML.

**I tried to not register the element but it doesn't seem to work.** It throws an exception if a constructor is invoked without registering a component. Since there are lots of demo components, it quickly becomes unwieldy to come up with unique names.

**Alternately, is there any way to use storybook for web-components without having to set up extra web components for stories?** *(I tried DOM manipulations but it also spirals out of hand.)*

Comment: What is the exlamation mark doing at the end of `this.shadowRoot!`?

Comment: You have to register custom components before using them. What's the problem with that?

Comment: @connexo, it's a TypeScript code.

Comment: @connexo https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes if you want to instantiate a Custom Element with `new`, you'll need to define it first with `customElements.define()`.

It's because your custom element derives from HTMLElement, so it must part of the Custom Elements Registry when `super()` is called from the `constructor()` method.

If you remove the `extends HTMLElement` and `super()` code parts from your class definition, you'll be able to instantiate it with `new` but it will a standard Javascript object, not a custom HTML element.