# Typescript and React compile errors

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am getting 2 typescript errors for el and modalRoot types. How should I declare el and modalRoot to get rid of typescript errors?

```
interface IModal {
  closeModal: () => {};
  title: string;
  children: ReactNode
}

const Modal = (props: IModal) => {
const {  closeModal, title, children } = props;
let el = null;
const modalRoot = document.getElementById('modal-root');

useEffect(() => {
  el = React.createElement('div');
  modalRoot.appendChild(el);
  return () => modalRoot.removeChild(el);
}, []);
....
}
```

Comment: 1) `modalRoot` could be null if the element doesn't exist 2) `el` is initially null, its type should be explicitly given.

Comment: My question is what should it be? I am new to typescript

Comment: use the [`!` operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) if you know for a fact the element exists. For the latter, type it.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply add an if statement in your hook:

```
useEffect(() => {
  el = React.createElement('div');
  if (!!el && !!modalRoot) {
    modalRoot.appendChild(el);
    return () => modalRoot.removeChild(el);
  }
}, []);
```