# In TypeScript, how to express a not-null condition will be true after a statement is called?

Tags: typescript

I have a class that employs lazy initialisation.

```
class LazyWorker {
    private state: string | undefined;

    lazyInit() {
        if (this.state === undefined) {
            //A lot of statements here
            //That are guaranteed to initialise the this.state property
            this.state = 'aaa'

            //I don't want to repeat those statements...
            //DRY principle, right? 
        }
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.lazyInit();

        this.state.startsWith('doSomething');
    }

    doSomethingElse() {
        this.lazyInit();

        this.state.endsWith('doSomethingElse');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, in the `doSomething` methods, the compiler complains that `this.state` might be `undefined`.

I can hack around compiler complaining by defining the property the following way, but it is inelegant and might give the false impression that the property is never undefined.

```
class LazyWorker {
    private state: string = undefined as any as string;
```

Any elegant way around it?

Comment: `this.state!.startsWith`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `state` is generally not `undefined` you might consider removing the undefined from the type and using a definite assignment assertion:

```
class LazyWorker {
    private state!: string;
    // ...
}
```

Another option is to use a not null assertion every time you access `state`:

```
class LazyWorker {
    private state: string | undefined;

    initializeState() {
        //A lot of statements here
        //That are guaranteed to initialise the this.state property
        this.state = 'aaa'

        //I don't want to repeat those statements...
        //DRY principle, right? 
    }

    doSomething() {
        this.initializeState();

        this.state!.startsWith('doSomething');
    }

    doSomethingElse() {
        this.initializeState();

        this.state!.endsWith('doSomethingElse');
    }
}
```

Both of these options are not type save and can cause run-time errors.

Typescript does not support custom assertion functions, it only supports type guards, which require an `if` to work as expected, but only for public properties. We can get this to work, but I'm not sure if it's not overkill:

```
class LazyWorker {
    state: string | undefined;

    initializeState(): this is this & { state: string } {
        //A lot of statements here
        //That are guaranteed to initialise the this.state property
        this.state = 'aaa'

        //I don't want to repeat those statements...
        //DRY principle, right? 
        return true;
    }

    doSomething() {
        if(!this.initializeState()) return;

        this.state.startsWith('doSomething');
    }

    doSomethingElse() {
        if(!this.initializeState()) return;

        this.state.endsWith('doSomethingElse');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. use  [non-null assertion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) (exclamation mark)

```
this.state!.startsWith('doSomething');
```

2. If possible, find a why to initialize state in the constructor

```
  private state: string;

  constructor() {
    this.state = 'aaa'
  }
```

Typescript is still new, and still require these kind of tweak to make it work properly.

For this matter, I think your suggested method is good as well, and in any case - [don’t let TypeScript slow you down](https://medium.com/@vitalyb/dont-let-typescript-slow-you-down-92d394ec8c9f)

Comment: Initialising the state in the constructor is against lazy-initialisation. It's done on purpose like that.