# TypeScript !. meaning

Tags: typescript

I was skimming through some [documentation in the Angular docs](https://material.angular.io/components/table/examples) and ran across this chunk of code:

```
return this.exampleDatabase!.getRepoIssues(
                this.sort.active, this.sort.direction, this.paginator.pageIndex);
```

Is this the TypeSrcript equivalent of the [C# null-conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) operator for null checking?

I tried doing some stuff in JSFiddle but kept getting syntax errors:

Example:

```
const obj = { test: 'ing 123' };

console.log(obj.test);
console.log(obj!.doesntexist); // Excepting null here
```

But, instead, I get:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token .
>       at new Function ()
>       at exec (typescript.js:41)
>       at HTMLDocument.runScripts (typescript.js:41)

Comment: Duplicate of [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's the [not-null-assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator). It basically tells typescript that the expression before it is **not** `null` and **not** `undefined`.

It's supposed to be used in cases where you as the developer are sure that a variable is defined but the compiler is unable to conclude that fact.

---

Looking into why this results in a syntax error on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/nowthced/1/)...

The transpiled code it's trying to run (using `new Function(transpiled)()`) contains this:

```js
console.log(obj, !.doesntexist);
```

I couldn't find out what version of TypeScript they're using exactly, but it must be older than 2.0 when the operator was introduced.

Comment: Thanks for the link. One question, why do I end up with a syntax error in my basic example?

Comment: Because you're using TypeScript syntax in JavaScript?

Comment: No, I've got JSFiddle set to use TypeScript

Comment: @mwilson Could you link the JSFiddle in your question?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/mswilson4040/nowthced/1/

Comment: Maybe JSFiddle is using some archaic version of TS. I haven't tried this code anywhere else.

Comment: @mwilson Yeah looks like they're using an old version (lower than 2.0). See the updated answer with some details.

Comment: If you don't need HTML or CSS I suggest the [official TypeScript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play) as an alternative to JSFiddle