# Exclamation Mark in type definition

Tags: angular, typescript

Currently I stumbled upon the [ContentChildren decorator](https://angular.io/api/core/ContentChildren) of Angular. In the first code example the following syntax is used:

```js
import {AfterContentInit, ContentChildren, Directive, QueryList} from '@angular/core';

@Directive({selector: 'child-directive'})
class ChildDirective {
}

@Directive({selector: 'someDir'})
class SomeDir implements AfterContentInit {
  @ContentChildren(ChildDirective) contentChildren !: QueryList<ChildDirective>;  // this line is relevant

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    // contentChildren is set
  }
}
```

Note the **exclamation mark followed by a colon** right after the `@ContentChildren(ChildDirective) contentChildren` variable definition. In [this StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) I discovered that this syntax can be used as a "non-null assertion operator" when accessing a variable or object property.

My question is now whether the exclamation mark before a type definition has exactly the same meaning like in a normal context. Does it simply say the TypeScript compiler: "Okay, don't worry about `null` or undefined", or does this syntax have another specific meaning in this context?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

> My question is now whether the exclamation mark before a type definition has exactly the same meaning like in a normal context.

No that's actually not the same thing, in this context it does something different. Normally when you declare a member (which doesnt' include `undefined` in it's type) it has to be initialized directly or in the constructor. If you add `!` after the name, TypeScript will ignore this and not show an error if you don't immediately initialize it:

```js
class Foo {
  foo: string; // error: Property 'foo' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.
  bar!: string; // no error
}
```

The same thing actually applies to local variables as well:

```js
let foo: string;
let bar!: string;

console.log(foo); // error: Variable 'foo' is used before being assigned.
console.log(bar); // no error
```

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgdgYwgJ2AQwJZygXigZ2GSwHMoAfKAVzgBMIAzLCWiqOKgG04G4AoPgk5p8+KADEA9pKgBvPlCgNpALgJFS-RQCM0yAIRrCxOCX4BfAZwjAlq9SbN9rt3QaMbT-QZLj5J1gB0nJIkABTKkgCU-Ai+-kEh4W4xQA)

Comment: This feature was added in TS2.7.  Relevant documentation: [definite assignment assertions with `!`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)

Comment: "Normally when you declare a member (which doesnt' include undefined in it's type) it has to be initialized directly or in the constructor" I believe by default it isn't. Only when `strictPropertyInitialization` is turned on directly or using `strict`.