# What is ! when declaring prop in VueJs

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js

I create a template VueJS using typescript, I found the example code has a line

```
export default class HelloWorld extends Vue {
  @Prop() private msg!: string;
}
```

If I remove `!`, vscode said

```
Property 'msg' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.Vetur(2564)
```

I searched `!` in Google but found nothing, what does it do exactly?

Comment: These two answers might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816914/exclamation-mark-in-type-definition/57816974#57816974 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/2404452

Comment: @sayalok: It's not, my question relates to `!`

Comment: Thank @blaz, I got it now

Comment: This feature was added in TS2.7.  Relevant documentation: [definite assignment assertions with `!`](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html#definite-assignment-assertions)