# What is the !: in typescript?

Tags: angular, typescript

I started learning typescript some days back and I got into this Angular project online.

When I declared a variable like so: `initPoint: Date;` within a class, vs-code highlighted this as an error *initPoint is not initialize* and the suggested quick fix was `initPoint!: Date`.

So my question is, what is this `!:` and why does it work but `initPoint: Date | undefined` does not work?
I don't actually know if this `!:` is typescript or angular - since I am completely new to both.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm I am not the question author, but it doesn't. That question is about `!` in expressions, this one is about `!` in property declaration. I can't find any relevant answers there either.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov here is a proper dup target: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816914/exclamation-mark-in-type-definition

Comment: @TobiasS. Great! Do you know if the current wrong target can be fixed?

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov - I guess only reopeing and closing again would fix it

Comment: This is still a answer you can easily find by using the search function. No need for score-hunting answers. I helped you voting to reopen to change the duplicate target, unfortunately I can't vote to close again