# Exclamation mark(!) and Question Mark(?) in typescript variable declaration

Tags: angular, typescript

What does ?(question mark) and the !(exclamation mark) means in declaring these variables in typescript?

```
title?: string;

form!: FormGroup;
```

Is this the same as non-null assertion operator?

Comment: Depends on where it occurs because the very same `title?: string` may be allowed in one place but forbidden in another Please give a bit more context

Comment: For the usage of `!`, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57816914/exclamation-mark-in-type-definition