# writing clean code: find an property in object-array with null-check

Tags: reactjs

I want to write clean-code. I have this react-code (typescript 3.6.4):

```
<Button color="primary"
    size="large"
    disabled={props.user.objectArray.find((element)=> {
                return element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey
            }).isClosed}
    onClick={doSomething}>
Download information
```

Now I get the message, that the return value could be "undefined". Understandable, maybe the primaryKey could not be found in the object array.

I could write a function which checks first for null, but could this be fixed anyhow without a function?

```
function getBooleanValue() {
    let booleanCheck = false;
    const temp = props.user.objectArray.find((element) => {
        return element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey
    });
    if (typeof temp !== "undefined") {
        booleanCheck = temp.siteClosed;
    }
    return booleanCheck;
}
```

How can I write a clean code to get my boolean value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start by storing the found element into a variable:

```
const foundElement = props.user.objectArray.find(element => element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey}
```

Then you can simply fix the condition:

```
// when element is not found, it's disabled
const isDisabled = !!foundElement && foundElement.isClosed
```

or

```
// when element is not found, it's not disabled 
const isDisabled = !foundElement || foundElement.isClosed
```

or you can use a default value:

```
const isDisabled = (foundElement || {}).isClosed
```

In total, the following could work:

```
(props.user.objectArray.find(element => element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey) || {}).isClosed
```

Comment: Still get the compiler error "Object is possibly undefined". I think I will stick with the function :-/

Comment: looks like [a TS bug](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/29642), the suggested workaround is to use `!`, the [non-null assertion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/1176601) => `(props.xxx || {})!.isClosed`

Answer (score 0):

I think you may try this way

```
<Button color="primary"
    size="large"
    disabled={props.user.objectArray.find((element)=> {
                return element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey
            }) && props.user.objectArray.find((element)=> {
                return element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey
            }).isClosed}
    onClick={doSomething}>
Download information
```

Here if 1st expression return falsy value then 2nd expression will execute, so if 1st expression is undefined javascript count it as falsy value and then `(...).isClosed` the 2nd part will not execute

Comment: Sadly, compiler is still complaining about the second "props.user.objectarray..." "Object is possibly undefined"

Comment: @Paul code should be like this, as props.user.objectArray is returning undefine 

`disabled={props.user.objectArray && props.user.objectArray.find((element)=> {
                return element.primaryKey === state.findPrimaryKey
            })}`

Comment: Maybe it is a compiler error, but Object is possibly undefined on second props.user... I will stay with a function. Thank you for your effort