# What does "!" (bang symbol) mean in a property declaration?

Tags: typescript

The code:

```js
class Cat extends Animal { tag! : 'cat' }
```

What does "!" mean after `tag` declaration? How is it different from just `tag`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: Definitely a duplicate.

Comment: I don't know, IMHO it's not a duplication, because the bang as operator removes "nullity", "undefinity" when you are sure in this, but in declaration, I don't know what it is

Comment: Even more, 3 cases: `tag: int`, `tag!: int`, `tag?: int`. What is the difference between 1st and 2nd ?

Comment: By removing this operator, the following typescript error will popup `Property 'tag' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)` therefore, you will shut the compiler up to complain about non constructor initialized properties, which is kind of a duplicate.

Comment: @r3dst0rm  I have not an error in `class Cat extends Animal { tag : 'cat' }`  declaration after removing of "!"

Comment: Your three cases: the first is simply defining a property tag with type int. The second makes the compiler silent about the possibility that it isn't initialized inside the constructor. The third makes the property optional and therefore either a int or undefined

Comment: Then it might be initialized inside your constructor?

Comment: Hm, maybe I miss something, but I don't see difference, I tried both cases and tsc did not show any error. Would you like to show some short example?

Comment: For sure, as the code is not a complete example I just added a bit more of code, like the Animal class/interface. https://codesandbox.io/s/k1i9q

Comment: Oh, I got the difference. @r3dst0rm if you want to add it as the answer, I will mark it as valid answer

Comment: This is definitely not a duplicate. Bang operators in property declarations have a different implication than in a function parameter list. See my comment to the response below.

Comment: It is not a duplicate. thanks @DanielHandojo

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let's look at an example - imagine we have the following code:

```js
interface Animal {
    tag: string;
}

class Cat implements Animal { tag: 'cat' }
```

```js
class AnimalClass {
    tag: string | undefined;
}

class Dog extends AnimalClass { tag: 'dog' }
```

Both code snippets would throw the following: `Property 'tag' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.(2564)`.

This is a feature of TypeScript added in 2.7.2 where it includes a strict class check, where all properties should be declared inside it's constructor.

By adding a bang sign `!`, you will override this behavior and tell the compiler you "know", that it is being initialized correctly and won't be undefined later on.

Also you can disable it by setting `"strictPropertyInitialization": false` inside your compiler options. Or you initialize the property where it should be initialized (according to TypeScript):

```js
class Dog extends AnimalClass { 
    tag: string;

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.tag = "";
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-7.html
https://github.com/prettier/prettier/issues/3561