# What does '!.' mean in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I've been trying to find the documentation for when you can use `!.` in javascript/typescript

I know that instead of doing

```
if (object && object.property) {

}
```

We can do using `!.`

```
if (object!.property) {

}
```

Are you able to nest the properties? For example.

```
object!.property!.name
```

Comment: Looks like TypeScript, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273853/107625).

Comment: O you're right! Thanks!

Comment: Does not exist in JavaScript, only in TypeScript. See the duplicate.