# How to return a null in Typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I would like to know whether this section of code is correct or there is a different way of defining it.

Instead of using error!, is there any way.
I would like to know what error! actually means as unable to understand.

Comment: [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853)

Comment: ... why did you just edit out the only piece of code, when the question is about that code?

Answer (score 2):

The code you have provided is correct if your expected behaviour is

1. To return the first error from `errors` array.
2. You are sure that `errors` array contains at least one error as you are returning an `ErrorResult` rather than `ErrorResult | undefined` or it's other equivalent.

You can re-write it as

```
// Typescripts infers the type of var to be `ErrorResult | undefined`
let error = errors.find(element => element.error);

// ! tells the compiler that you know error is not `undefined`
return error!;
```

Answer (score 1):

- Then `!` mark after `variable` is known as `bang operator` or `non-null assertion operator`. In your case you are returning `ErrorResult` from your `function` I guess. Which should not be `null`.
- But you have some specific requirement and you want to return `null` also.
- If you don't write `!` after `variable` then your code may show `compile time error`. But if you add `!` then it will `compile` without error.
- But here you need to make sure that whenever you are working with returned value, you should define it as `ErrorResult | undefined` otherwise it may raise an `exception` at `run time`.

Here are some links which will be helpful to understand the concept better.

1. [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)
2. [Cleaner TypeScript With the Non-Null Assertion Operator](https://medium.com/better-programming/cleaner-typescript-with-the-non-null-assertion-operator-300789388376)

```js
class ErrorResult {
  error: boolean
  constructor(error: boolean) {
    this.error = error;
  }
}

function getError(errors: ErrorResult[]) {
  let error: ErrorResult;
  errors.forEach(element => {
    if (element.error === true) {
      error = element;
    }
  });
  return error!;
}

let myError: ErrorResult | undefined;
myError = getError([new ErrorResult(false)]);
console.log(myError);

let myError2: ErrorResult | undefined;
myError2 = getError([new ErrorResult(true)]);
console.log(myError2);
```