# Change Typescript interface property from optional to defined

Tags: typescript

It's pretty hard to explain since I don't know all the terminology yet. But here it goes:

Given the following interface with the optional property 'id'.

```
interface User {
  id?: string;
  name: string;
}
```

In some parts of the application the `id` property is undefined (yet). But at a certain point in my application I know for sure that the `id` is there.

```
// at this point user.id is definitely defined
users.map((user: User) => {
  return (<p>{user.name} with the id: {user.id}<p>)
  // TS error: Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.
});
```

Now I can add an 'if' statement to solve this issue. But is there a way that I can 'tell' Typescript that the ID property now is available for sure? Or is that not smart to do...

Ideally I do not want to have to maintain another interface or alias with the id property non-optional.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: Try changing from ```{user.id}``` to ```{user?.id}```.

Comment: If your are really sure that the `id` is defined, then you can cast it using `{user.id as string}`. But I really recommand you to use an `if` statement instead.

Comment: Thanks guys. I remembered the bang operator. Seems like an elegant solution. ESLint is complaining though, so I accepted Rubydesic's answer. The typecasting was also a good suggestion. Adding the if statement is the wisest to prevent future changes. But having all those if statements makes the code so bloated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the type of `User` when you assign the IDs:

```
interface IdUser extends User {
    id: string
}

function assignId(user: User): IdUser {
    return {...user, id: 'id' };
}
```