# what does the `!.` operator means in typescript?

Tags: typescript

In vue-next, I found a new usage of `!.` symbols. Can anyone explain what this means?
[image]

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Comment: [Please don't post images of code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)