# TypeScript cant read property addEventListener

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm learning **TypeScript** and I'm following a youtube tutorial that I did step by step. But for some reason I'm still receving a error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null**

I rewrote the code twice and I'm still receiving the same error. Could u guys pls help me understand what's wrong and why.

I'm still a rookie, but it's driving me crazy.

Tks in advanced.

```
//Interface
interface PersonObjInterface{
    name: string,
    age: number
}

//Interface for Obj
let objPerson: PersonObjInterface = {
    name: "John Doe",
    age: 40
}

//Interface for Class
class ClassPerson implements PersonObjInterface{
    constructor(public name: string, public age: number){}
    greet(){
        return `Hi, my name is ${this.name} and I am ${this.age} yo.`
    }
}

//let John = new ClassPerson("John", 40)
//console.log(John.greet());

//DOM
const inputName = document.querySelector('#name') as HTMLInputElement
const inputAge = document.querySelector('#age') as HTMLInputElement
const inputForm = document.querySelector('form')!
const greeting = document.querySelector('.greeting') as HTMLDivElement

inputForm.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const person = new ClassPerson(inputName.value, inputAge.valueAsNumber)
    greeting.innerText = person.greet()
    inputForm.reset()
})
```

The html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <title>TypeScript Crash Course</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form>
        <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
        <input type="number" name="age" id="age" />
        <input type="submit" value="Say hi" />
    </form>
    <div class="greeting"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: whats the ! a the end of the const inputForm = document.querySelector('form')! line for

Comment: ```console.log('form')``` and see is it what you expected?

Comment: @tsecheukfung01 that would clearly print `form` so how does that help?

Comment: When does this code run? In the `head` of the HTML document or at the bottom of the `body`? If it is in the `head`, you must wait until the document is loaded before attempting to access the DOM.

Comment: May be a dumb question, but do you actually have a `<form> ..</form>` element in your DOM, and is it already rendered when you run this code?

Comment: @MattEvans i'ts to tell that form really exist

Comment: @spender its on header I edit the post with the html now

Comment: @derpirscher yes. I posted the html now as u can see :)

Comment: @EversonCarvalho you may have a <form> in your html code, but it's not rendered yet at the time, the code is run. See my answer how to fix that.

Comment: @EversonCarvalho like a null check? Interesting, thanks

Comment: @MattEvans No, it's not a null check, but a non-null-assertion. And it's compiletime only! It has no whatsoever effect in the resulting JS code, because it's removed during compilation.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are loading your `app.js` in the header of your html document. At this time, there is no `<body>` or `<form>`, because the DOM is not fully loaded yet. So all your `document.querySelector()` calls will return `null`.

The easiest solution is to load your script in the end of the HTML document, so all the DOM elements already exist.

```
<html>
<head>
 ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
  <script src="app.js"></script>  <!-- move script loading from head to here -->
</body>
</html>
```

As an alternative you can also use the [`defer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script) attribute when loading your script, which will execute the script only after the page has loaded, reagardless where the `script` tag is placed. But this only works for external scripts loaded via `src=...` attribute.

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="app.js" defer></script> 
 ...
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're right Sir. I thought about that during lunch and none of my "js" was loading for these reason. ty.