# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null at app.js:5

Tags: javascript, html, navigationbar

**In onclick function showing a error canot set property of null , this used for navigation bar**

```
const body = document.querySelector("body");
const navbar = document.querySelector(".navbar");
const menuBtn = document.querySelector(".menu-btn");
const cancelBtn = document.querySelector(".cancel-btn");
menuBtn.onclick=()=>{
  navbar.classList.add("show");
  menuBtn.classList.add("hide");
  body.classList.add("disabled");
};
cancelBtn.onclick=()=>{
  body.classList.remove("disabled");
  navbar.classList.remove("show");
  menuBtn.classList.remove("hide");
};
window.onscroll=()=>{
  this.scrollY > 20
    ? navbar.classList.add("sticky")
    : navbar.classList.remove("sticky");
};
```

Comment: Please also show your HTML... it seems like the menuBtn or cancelBtn don't exist.

Comment: Don’t use `.onclick`, `.onscroll`, etc. Use [`.addEventListener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead. Instead of your `body` variable simply use `document.body`. Instead of the `scroll` event use CSS `@media` queries, or at least instead of the conditional operator, use [`navbar.classList.toggle("sticky", scrollY > 20);`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMTokenList/toggle).

Comment: Is your `<script>` _above_ your HTML with no `defer` attribute? See [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as `getElementById` not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/4642212).

Comment: probably you are loading your script in the head of your html document, thus, the DOM elements do not exist yet. Either use `defer` or place the `<script>` tag at the bottom of your html document.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript cant read property addEventListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66549448/typescript-cant-read-property-addeventlistener)

Comment: Please put up a complete example which shows the error and is in a Stackoverflow snippet otherwise we start guessing what the problem is. Also, your dev tools will show you which line has the error.

Comment: @AHaworth _“Also, your dev tools will show you which line has the error. ”_ — The line number is already included in the title: it’s the line with `menuBtn.onclick`.