# Detect data changes on dynamic component is not working

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm working with dynamic components, I followed this [tutorial](https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader) and works fine.

This is my implementation

**dynamic-component.directive.ts**

```js
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';    
@Directive({
    selector: '[DynamicComponent]'
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective {
    constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```

And, this is the logic, to create dynamic components. It can detect when data is emitted with `@Output`
This is the code

```js
import { Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, EventEmitter, Input, OnChanges, OnDestroy, OnInit, Output, SimpleChanges, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicComponentDirective } from './dynamic-component.directive';
import { DynamicComponentInterface } from '@interfaces/dynamic-component.interface';

@Component({
    selector: 'dynamic-component',
    template: '<ng-template DynamicComponent></ng-template>'
})
export class DynamicComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy, OnChanges {

    @Input() component!: DynamicComponentInterface;
    @Output() sentData: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

    @ViewChild(DynamicComponentDirective, { static: true })
    directive!: DynamicComponentDirective;
    componentRef!: ComponentRef<DynamicComponentInterface>;
    constructor(
    private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver
    ) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
    if ( this.component ) {
        this.loadComponent();
    }
    }

    ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.componentRef.destroy();
    }

    ngOnChanges( changes: SimpleChanges ): void {
    console.log( changes );
    }



    loadComponent(): void {


    const componentFactory = this.factoryResolver
    .resolveComponentFactory( this.component.component );


    const containerRef = this.directive.viewContainerRef;

    this.componentRef = containerRef
    .createComponent<DynamicComponentInterface>( componentFactory );


    this.componentRef.instance.data = this.component.data;
    this.componentRef.instance.emitter?.
    subscribe( (values: any) => this.sentData.emit( values ) );
    this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();
    }
}
```

All works fine, This is my how it works...

in the **app.component.html**

```html
<mat-accordion [multi]="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let expansion of salaryPanelRight" [expanded]="true">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        {{ expansion.title }}
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>

    <dynamic-component [component]="expansion.panel"></dynamic-component>
    </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

This is how the `dynamic-component` builds on the logic file

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { DynamicComponentInterface } from '@interfaces/dynamic-component.interface';
import { PanelJobDetailsComponent } from './components/panel-job-details/panel-job-details.component';
import { PanelSalaryDetailsResumeComponent } from './components/panel-salary-details-resume/panel-salary-details-resume.component';
import { PanelSalaryResumeComponent } from './components/panel-salary-resume/panel-salary-resume.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'app-salary-data',
    templateUrl: './salary-data.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./salary-data.component.scss']
})
export class SalaryDataComponent {
    salaryPanelRight: SalaryPanel [] = [
    {
        title: $localize`:@@salary-tab-panel-resume-details: Title 1`,
        panel: {
        component: PanelJobDetailsComponent,
        data: {
            hireSchema: null
        }
        },
    },
    {
        title: $localize`:@@salary-tab-panel-resume-salary: Title 2`,
        panel: {
        component: PanelSalaryResumeComponent
        }
    },
    {
        title: $localize`:@@salary-tab-panel-resume-salary-details: Title 3`,
        panel: {
        component: PanelSalaryDetailsResumeComponent
        }
    },
    ];
    constructor() { }

    getValues( input: any ): void {
    const value = input.target.value;
    this.salaryPanelRight[0].panel.data.hireSchema = value;
    }

}

interface SalaryPanel {
    title: string;
    panel: DynamicComponentInterface;
}
```

For example `PanelJobDetailsComponent` has this `@Input() hireSchema!: string;` and his HTML is only `{{ hireSchema }}`

It is not changing when I change the value from parent component, exactly in this part

```js
      getValues( input: any ): void {
        const value = input.target.value;
        this.salaryPanelRight[0].panel.data.hireSchema = value;
      }
```

I have read and implemented `ngOnChanges` but is not working, the data is not changing. Actually I did `this.componentRef.changeDetectorRef.detectChanges();` also but it is not working. When I do `console.log` on `ngOnChanges` nothing is happening, even I fired blur event from the input to fire the new data.

How can I pass the changed data to my implementation?

Comment: have you tried triggering change detection manually?

Comment: How could I do that?

Comment: `constructor(private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef){}` and then use it in the line after you set the data like `this.cdr.detectChanges()`

Comment: Is not happening anything, what could be the problem?

Comment: why do you have ! in your property definitions `@Input() component!: DynamicComponentInterface;`

Comment: Typescript says: `component has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`

Comment: @Kieran You can find about `!` in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/5107490

Comment: Why `@Input` doesn't trigger change detection is because you don't use the input. You are using a direct property access. I would use setters for inputs and call `markForCheck()` when the value changes. Should do the trick

Comment: Here is why `ngOnChanges` not working for you https://indepth.dev/posts/1054/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular#ngonchanges

Answer (score 5):

Why `ngOnChanges` is not working is explained in [this article](https://indepth.dev/posts/1054/here-is-what-you-need-to-know-about-dynamic-components-in-angular#ngonchanges).

In order to have your change detection work you could create setters in your dynamic components and call `changeDetectorRef.markForCheck()` from them. I would not recommend using `detectChanges` as it may create more problems than it solves if used not very carefully

Answer (score -1):

Assign a new array to `salaryPanelRight` member variable whenever you make any changes to the array contents. Then `ngOnChanges()` will be fired when there is a change in the array reference, there wont be any change detected when content of the array is modified.

```
this.salaryPanelRight = this.salaryPanelRight.slice(0);
```

Answer (score -1):

Its not possible for a dynamically created component to be aware of changes.

What worked for me was triggering change detection at the time the component was made.

```
this.containerFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(ValuePolicyComponent);
        this.newComponent = 
        this.viewContainerRef.createComponent(this.containerFactory);
        this.newComponent.instance.template = this.templateRef;
        this.newComponent.instance.valueKey = this.nxValuePolicy;
        this.newComponent.instance.featureKey = this.featureKey;
        const cdr = this.newComponent.injector.get(ChangeDetectorRef);
        cdr.detectChanges();
```

(maybe this is not necessary if the parent component is using default change detection)

Comment: Does not work for me.