# loginForm!: FormGroup; VS loginForm: FormGroup | undefined;

Tags: angular

What is the difference between the following declarations?

```
 loginForm!: FormGroup;


 loginForm: FormGroup | undefined;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Answer (score 1):

When you just declare a variable without initialized, you get will an error from editor itself, something like this:

```
angular Type 'null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormGroup | undefined' or initialized variable in constructor
```

This happen due to typescript version 2.1 or above.

If you want to prevent from such error, you have to use **"Definite Assignment Assertion"** feature,  with your variable or you have to initialized the variable within constructor,

**'Definite Assignment Assertion' or '!'** is a feature in typescript, and it also called **non-null assertion operator**. It will tell typescript that this variable will have a value at runtime.

Another approach which you mentioned in your question, is not a recommended approach, it may prevent you from runtime error but it doesn't make a sense to provide the undefined parallels to Type