# Declare optional value as definitely defined later

Tags: typescript

Let's say I define an interface like this

```
interface User {
  name: string;
  address?: SomeObject;
}
```

Later in the code I definitely define it through some dynamic process. Because I can't/don't want to initially define it with a dummy object.

Then I want to use it like this in a function

```
const foo=(name:string, address: SomeObject)=>{
   console.log(address);
}
```

If I use it like this

```
foo(user.name, user.address)
```

I will get that param2 is possibly undefined.

If I do it like this

```
const foo=(name:string, address?: SomeObject)=>{
   console.log(address);
}
```

Then I can call the function but I would have to check inside the function body whether address is defined.

What I want to know if I can to is something like this

```
const foo=(name:string, address: SomeObject)=>{
       console.log(address);
    }
foo(user.name, user.address!) //where ! is a made up operator that says this object is definitely defined.
```

tldr: I want to know if there is a way to say to TS that this possibly undefined value is certainly defined by this time of execution.

Comment: [`Required<SomeObject>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#requiredtype)?

Comment: @VLAZ no that wouldn't solve it.

Comment: Then I don't know what you need. You say `!` is made up operator [but seems to be exactly what you need](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=10&ssc=2&pln=11&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoHsC2EDyAjAKwgTGQG8BYAKGVuQA8AuZEAV0z2gG5qBfa0JFiIUAVQDO0ctTos42ZuLBRQAcx406cACbaoEceID8zDNnxESG-lQToQS5DHTpkAXmQAKEPIiLlagA0yDp6BuKmWLiExGAAlO4AfNKatHYO6AA2EAB0meiqnqH6hnHW1NTaxJlw+sjpjqySUMwS3BVUzuieTdA5PtjBvVA5xeEAhGVAA). I was struggling to find a different way to do the same without `!`. Can you explain what the problem is with the non-null assertion?

Comment: I swear to god I looked everywhere for this and did not find it and i just assumed i doesn't exist. Thank you for answering!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)