# Compile time error after using PrimeNG table for filtering data in textbox

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, primeng-datatable

I have created a project in **Angular 12 version**. Then I have installed the **most recent version (11.4.5) of  PrimeNG controls** in my project. Now I have created a page to use PrimeNG Table with sorting and filtering features. *Below the header I have another row to contain the textbox for filtering the data.*

Now I want, whenever I input any value in the textbox the table rows will automatically be filtered. I don't want to use enter after inputting any value in the textbox for filtering. But I am facing some compiling errors.

**HTML file:**

```
<p-table #dt1 [columns]="cols" [value]="products" dataKey="id" styleClass="p-datatable-gridlines p-datatable-striped"
    [paginator]="true" [rows]="5" [showCurrentPageReport]="true"
    currentPageReportTemplate="Showing {first} to {last} of {totalRecords} entries" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[5,10,20]">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header" let-columns>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" pSortableColumn="{{col.field}}">
                {{col.header}}
                <p-sortIcon field="{{col.field}}"></p-sortIcon>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th *ngFor="let col of columns" [ngSwitch]="col.field">
                <p-columnFilter *ngSwitchCase="'name'" type="text" field="name" matchMode="contains" [ngModel]="value"
                    (input)="dt1.filter($event.target.value)">
                </p-columnFilter>
            </th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-rowData let-columns="columns">
        <tr>
            <td *ngFor="let col of columns">
                {{rowData[col.field]}}
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

**TS file:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../_models/product.model';
import { ProductService } from '../_services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dynamic-grid',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-grid.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-grid.component.css']
})
export class DynamicGridComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  cols: any[] = [];

  value:any = null;

  constructor(private productService: ProductService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.productService.getProductsSmall().then(data => this.products = data);

    this.cols = [
      { field: 'code', header: 'Code' },
      { field: 'name', header: 'Name' },
      { field: 'category', header: 'Category' },
      { field: 'quantity', header: 'Quantity' }
    ];
  }
}
```

**Model:**

```js
export interface Product {
    id?: string;
    code?: string;
    name?: string;
    description?: string;
    price?: number;
    quantity?: number;
    inventoryStatus?: string;
    category?: string;
    image?: string;
    rating?: number;
}
```

**The compile error is:**

> Error: src/app/dynamic-grid/dynamic-grid.component.html:19:40 - error
> TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.
>
> 19      (input)="dt1.filter($event.target.value)">
> ~~~~~
>
> src/app/dynamic-grid/dynamic-grid.component.ts:7:16
> 7   templateUrl: './dynamic-grid.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component DynamicGridComponent.
>
> Error: src/app/dynamic-grid/dynamic-grid.component.html:19:40 - error
> TS2531: Object is possibly 'null'.
>
> 19      (input)="dt1.filter($event.target.value)">
> ~~~~~
>
> src/app/dynamic-grid/dynamic-grid.component.ts:7:16
> 7   templateUrl: './dynamic-grid.component.html',
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> Error occurs in the template of component DynamicGridComponent.
>
> ** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **

[image]

Can anyone help me to solve the problem please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get this error as you enable [`strictTemplate`](https://angular.io/guide/angular-compiler-options#stricttemplates) in tsconfig.json.

> error TS2339: Property 'value' does not exist on type 'EventTarget'.

**Not recommended to disable the settings in tsconfig.json**.

---

### Solution

You can write a custom filter `applyFilter` which receives `$event`, `field` and `matchMode` parameters.

> .component.html

```
<p-columnFilter *ngSwitchCase="'name'" type="text" field="name" matchMode="contains"
  (input)="applyFilter($event, 'name', 'contains')">
</p-columnFilter>
```

> .component.ts

```js
import { ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

@ViewChild('dt1') dt!: Table;

applyFilter($event: any, field: string, matchMode: string) {
  let value = ($event.target as HTMLInputElement)?.value;
  this.dt.filter(value, field, matchMode);
}
```

[Sample Solution on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-uey5bk)

Comment: Why '!' sign is used after dt?

Comment: The ! sign means the variable is not null nor undefined. 

You may refer to this question: [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci).