# Angular | Typescript | ngxs state Observable: What does a variable ending with ! represent. @Select(someSelector) var $!: Observable<someType[]>>

Tags: angular, typescript, selector, store, ngxs

In my TS file, i have a declaration like

```
import { Select } from '@ngxs/store';
@Injectable()
export class someService {
@Select(someSELECTOR) varName$!: Observable<someType[]>;

  elements$ = this.varName$.pipe(
    map(elements => elements.map(SOMElogic),
  );
}
```

My question is in "**varName$!**", I know we use **$** for representing observable, any idea what **!** represents.
Its not part of variable name, as when it is used below with pipe the **!** is missing.

Does it represent anything in NGXS or Typscript or Angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) The "!" is the *non-null-assertion* operator of TypeScript. It doesn't represent anything NGRX or Angular specific.