# Exclamation point and dot in JS or TS (ex: obj.prop!.value)

Tags: javascript, typescript

I was reading this [article](https://blog.logrocket.com/using-observables-transform-data-typescript/) on using observables and came across several instances where the writer wrote something like this:

```js
map((value: IObj) => {
  return value.name!.value; // << What is this??
})
```

I've never seen this exclamation point and dot combo before. The writer does this a few times in the article for me to think that it's a typo. I know about `?.` but I've never seen `!.` in JS, TypeScript, or Flow.

Can someone help me understand what that is? Specifically:

- what is it called?
- Is it JS or TS?
- If JS, when was it introduced?
- Most importantly, what does it do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In Typescript, what is the ! (exclamation mark / bang) operator when dereferencing a member?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci)

Comment: Postfix `!` is the TS non-null assertion operator. `.` is a plain JS property access.