# Selector changes by an index in Mobile vs Desktop. How to handle assertion in Cypress

Tags: typescript, cypress

I have a selector that changes when running in mobile. For example:

Desktop: `div[data-test-id="popup"] div:nth-child(2)`
Mobile: `div[data-test-id="popup"] div:nth-child(3)`

My idea is to check the size of the window and if it's below 375 use the Mobile selector else Desktop.

I have the following working solution but I dont want to have repeated code and rather would like to pass 2 or 3 as a parameter:

```
cy.get('body').then( (body) => {
       if ( body.width() <= 375 ) {
           cy.get('div[data-test-id="popup"] div:nth-child(3)')
               .children().eq(0)
               .should('exist')
               .should('have.text', time);
       }
       else {
           cy.get('div[data-test-id="popup"] div:nth-child(2)')
               .children().eq(0)
               .should('exist')
               .should('have.text', time);
       }
    });
```

Is there a better way to rewrite it?

Also, the above code, even though it runs and the tests pass, the build fails with a Typescript error due to `body.width()` --> `TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'`.

Comment: You might get a better solution if you could post the DOM section containing the element you are wanting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be testing both desktop and mobile using [viewport](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/viewport) to explicitly set the width

```js
const widths = [500, 350]
widths.forEach(width => {

  // You are looking for a way to parameterize the selector,
  // do it using a template literal
  const param = width === 350 ? 3 : 2
  const selector = `div[data-test-id="popup"] div:nth-child(${param})`

  beforeEach(() => {
    cy.viewport(width, 800)
  })

  it(`tests the width of ${width}px`, () => {
    cy.get(selector)
      .children().eq(0)
      .should('exist')
      .should('have.text', time)
  })
})
```

It looks like you need to use viewport in a somewhat restricted way, either

- in beforeEach() hook
- before a page cy.visit()
- before a page cy.reload()

---

The typescript error

> body.width() --> TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'

can be fixed by using the [non-null assertion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42274019/16997707)

```
body!.width()   // telling typescript that we know body exists
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using the `.contains()` command instead of the all the `.get()`s.

Assuming you don't have any other elements with `data-test-id="popup"` with the time text or any nested `data-testid="popup"` within the `div[data-test-id="popup"` one, then this will work for both desktop and mobile and here is what it will look like.

```
cy.contains('[data-test-id=popup]', time) 
  .should('exist')
  .should('have.text', time);
```