# Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm looking answer of this question but I can't find it. So, I have this interface:

```
export interface productsListFromOrder{
  product_name: string,
  amount: number,
  price: number,
}
```

I made the array of this objects and I push that:

```
  products:productsListFromOrder[] = []; //productsListFormOrder is my interface
  myFunction(): void{
//...
        this.products.push({
          product_name: product?.name!,
          price: product?.price!,
          amount: element.amount ? parseInt(element.amount) : 1
        })
}
```

Problem is that I have an error from title:

> Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number'
> I'm sure that type is correct becouse i test a few things:

1. I display type of price and it display **number**

`console.log(typeof product?.price!);`

2. I set type of products array on any[] and it works correctly but I want to use my interace

`products:productsListFromOrder[] = [];`

3. I solve this problem in this way

`regular_price: typeof product?.price! == 'boolean' ? 0 : product?.price!,`

Ok, if I use method 2 or 3, my code works but it doesn't my goal. **I need to use my interace** (instead of any[] like in point 2) and **code from point 3 is ugly**. And what is **the most important** - **why I have this error? Product.price has a type number**. How can I write this code without typeof checking?

Comment: What is  the interface for `product`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/mAyPQm) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: Object type names are conventionally written in UpperPascalCase to distinguish them from value names and primitive types; please change `productsListFromOrder` to `ProductsListFromOrder` so as not to distract attention from your issue.

Answer (score 0):

The exclamation operation in TypeScript is called "Non-Null Assertion Operator"
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42273853/4604645) and answers provide a good deep dive on what it means.

When you do this:

```
 product?.name!,
```

It is incorrect. As your are using the question mark operator (which would potentially allow `product?.name` to be null or undefined) prior to the exclamation mark operator (which asserts `product?.name` not to be null or undefined).

I believe you have disabled a some of the type script validations otherwise you'd be received the following errors:

`product?.name!`:

> TSLint: Forbidden non null assertion(no-non-null-assertion)

having the interface name `productsListFromOrder` in lowercase:

> TSLint: Class name must be in pascal case

This second is a simple fix as pointed by jcalz's comments, change it to `ProductsListFromOrder`

Regarding the error "Type 'boolean' is not assignable to type 'number' "

I would suggest that you variable `product` here:

```
       this.products.push({
          product_name: product?.name!,
          price: product?.price!,
          amount: element.amount ? parseInt(element.amount) : 1
        })
```

Somehow has its `price` attribute with an implicit interface of as boolean. Which in turn causes the error you are getting.

To resolve it,

#### Option 1 (ugly)

you could coarse the value of `price` to number:

```
  price: <number><unknown>product?.price,
```

#### Option 2 (my recommendation)

you should adjust the variable `product` so it can never provide an interface of boolean for its price property.