# Using different URLs for local and CI testing

Tags: continuous-integration, cypress

I want to use Cypress to test locally and on CI at the same time. On CI, I would like to test a production version of my application, which has a different baseUrl than the local version, obviously. I am using the https://github.com/bjowes/cypress-ntlm-auth package to ause windows authentication for the CI, and to do so I have to call cy.ntlm line in my tests. I want to make an IF function that calls the cy.ntlm line ONLY if the baseUrl matches the production one. If the baseUrl is localhost then I would like the cy.ntlm line to be ignored. So my bottom line questions are, how do I let cypress know that I want to use 2 different URLs and how do I pack that into an IF statement? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the baseUrl to conditionally call `cy.ntlm`,

```js
const baseUrl = Cypress.config('baseUrl')!  // use non-null assertion operator

const isLocal = baseUrl.includes('localhost')

if (!isLocal) {
  cy.ntlm(...)
}
```

When using Typescript with Cypress you will get complaints because Typescript has no idea if you have set the `baseUrl` configuration or not.

You can overcome that by adding `!` after getting the `baseUrl` value.
Ref [Typescript - Non-null assertion operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-0.html#non-null-assertion-operator)

I separated the steps to make it clearer.

Comment: It does not let me use this as it complains about (!Cypress.config("baseUrl") possibly being null. If I try to use (!Cypress.config("baseUrl", "**localhost**") then it's no longer a Boolean, it becomes a Void statement.  TypeScript is in question.

Comment: You could resolve this by just requiring that `Cypress.config('baseUrl')` is not null - `!Cypress.config('baseUrl')!!.includes(...)`

Comment: It's a Typescript error, you can fix it with a [non-null assertion operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci).

Comment: Thanks guys, I did use the non-null and added a rule for that next line to not be considered with es lint. Appreciate the help. This is the solution in the end and it works: // eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
  if (!Cypress.config().baseUrl!.includes("localhost")) {
    // eslint-disable-next-line  @typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion
    const url = new URL(Cypress.config().baseUrl!);
    const host = `${url.hostname}:${url.port}`;
    cy.ntlm([host], Cypress.env("USER"), Cypress.env("PASS"));
  };

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your cypress config file has the `baseUrl`. You can then update the baseUrl using the CLI during run time. For this create two different scripts with the staging and production URL's in your `package.json` like this:

```js
"scripts": {
  "test:local": "cypress run --config baseUrl=https://example.com/staging",
  "test:ci": "cypress run --config baseUrl=https://example.com/production"
}
```

Then to run the scripts in CI use `npm run test:ci` and for local use `npm run test:local`.

Comment: Thank you and apologies, I have already made these before asking the question, I should have mentioned that. I just was not sure if there was a way to include different URLs in the If statement. I appreciate the help.