# Tell TS that function argument ran and to respects its side effects

Tags: typescript

I have a `retry` util that takes a function as an argument. This retry util defines a variable in the scope.

```
let code: number;

retry(() => {
  code = 123;
});

const msg = `Your code is: ${code}!`;
console.log('msg:', msg);

function retry(cb: () => void) {
  cb();
}
```

Typescript underlines `code` with error:

> Variable 'code' is used before being assigned.(2454)

Because it doesn't know that `cb` got ran. Is it possible to type up `retry` such that TS knows the `cb` argument ran? So it applies the type affects of that argument?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is tell the compiler that you are sure this variable was assigned to a value, like this:

```
let code: number;

retry(() => {
  code = 123;
});

const msg = `Your code is: ${code!}!`;
console.log('msg:', msg);

function retry(cb: () => void) {
  cb();
}
```

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci) for more information on the "!" operator

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to avoid `!` though and was trying to get TS to read the flow, is that possible?

Comment: I don't know any way to do that...