# Would like an explanation on the @Input decorator in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm learning Angular and in the tutorial I've been working with, there is this line of code:

```
@Input() product!: Product;
```

I'm wondering what the ! means in this context.
Thanks in advance to all who respond.

Comment: not related to angular, but typescript: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42273853/in-typescript-what-is-the-exclamation-mark-bang-operator-when-dereferenci

Comment: It means the same as in TypeScript. This property will never be null.