# Type narrowing doens't work as expected for object

Tags: typescript

```js
interface Obj {
  foo?: string;
  bar?: string;
}

const fn = (obj: Obj, key: keyof Obj) => {
  if (obj.foo) {
    const val1 = obj.foo; // string
  }

  if (obj['foo']) {
    const val2 = obj['foo'] // string
  }

  const picked = obj[key];

  if (picked) {
    const val3 = picked; // string
  }

  if (obj[key]) {
    const val4 = obj[key]; // string | undefined
  }
};
```

I wonder why type narrowing doesn't work in case of `val4`.

I know I can use `!` or custom defined type guards [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597425/how-to-tell-typescript-that-optional-property-in-object-exists-and-is-set/52018536#52018536). But what I want to know is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

Narowing does not work on dynamic access to the object (access with `[]` and a variable as the index). This limitation is due to performance reasons. You can search GitHub for issues around this, [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/11483) is one.